# GridLayout support width issue

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-support-library

I'm using support v7 `GridLayout` but as many others noted, it does not measure its children width correctly.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239966/android-gridlayout-not-clipping-text-to-column-width), there's a workaround but the workaround works randomly for me, for some values it works, and for some children values it doesn't.

The proposed workaround:

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

I set child values during runtime so my guess is only toward measuring children width.

[image]

Comment: Same problem using native GridLayout !

Comment: There *is* a consistent way to use `TextView` inside `GridLayout`. Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23090059/1208581

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the workaround you mentioned, proposed here: [Android GridLayout not clipping text to column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239966/android-gridlayout-not-clipping-text-to-column-width) and here [Daniel Lew's Coding Thoughts  GridLayout Child View Clipping Issues](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.jp/2012/01/gridlayout-view-clipping-issues.html) works:

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

In my case it worked properly even when setting the child values programmatically when I applied to all children in the last column, like in the following example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowCount="2"
    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Label1"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLabel1"
        grid:layout_row="0"
        grid:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        grid:layout_gravity='fill_horizontal'
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value1"
        android:id="@+id/textViewValue1"
        grid:layout_row="0"
        grid:layout_column="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Label2"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLabel2"
        grid:layout_row="1"
        grid:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        grid:layout_gravity='fill_horizontal'
        android:text="Value2"
        android:id="@+id/textViewValue2"
        grid:layout_row="1"
        grid:layout_column="1" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this code solves the problem?