# Android - GridLayout cell sizes

Tags: android, grid

I am trying to use GridLayout with ImageViews. My problem is that the images I have are all different sizes. I have set the row count and column count, but somehow I need to set a fixed cell size (somehow uniform - as in cell width = total / num of columns, and cell height = total / num of rows). I want to do this so that when I set height and width of imageview to match_parent, the image view doesn't expand beyond the cell size and the layout looks uniform.

I need 5 rows and 3 columns. Can someone suggest how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890588/long-text-on-button-messes-up-gridlayout-rows/23890689#23890689). The theory is to use a wrapper layout for your cell and provide the margins that it needs to it. Then use the imageview inside this layout. Thus the outer layout acts as a container for your imageview and it will never go out of the bound of its parent.